# Extra memory consumption b/w l +=c and l = c+l?

Tags: c++, string, memory, c++17

I was solving a  question in which I have to add a single character in front of a string multiple times so I just use

`string l ="";`

`char c = 'x';`

`l = c+l;`

but when I run it, it shows the memory limit is exceeded?
Instead when I used

`string l ="";`

`char c = 'x';`

`l += c;`

`reverse(l.begin(),l.end());`

It was compiled successfully.
I want to know why this is happening?

Comment: `c+l` results in a new string object. Which memory do you think it should use to store its data, which is all of the old string contents prefixed with the new character?

Comment: `l.insert(l.begin(), c);` will _probably_ be faster than `l = c+l;` but will still suffer from having to move the existing `char`s one step to the "right".

Comment: Very important:  The Right-Hand side of an assignment statement is evaluated before the assignment takes place.  This means there needs to an `operator+(char, std::string)` before the assignment occurs.  The compiler may do due diligence and see if there are any functions or operators that can lead up to or convert types to match the `operator+` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned adding a char to the front of the string will create a new string and copy every single time while adding a char to the back will grow the capacity in larger steps and only copy occasionally.

But both ways use <= 2N memory. The used memory for both ways isn't too different. The issue with adding to the front is time, not space.

What the test probably notices though is fragmentation of the free memory. In the first case the libc will allocate a block of memory for every size of string 1 - N and promptly free it again. But the blocks used for smaller strings can't be reused for larger strings unless 2 adjacent small strings are freed and merged into a larger block of reusable memory. For the last step you have a string of size N-1 and size N. If the malloc simply uses a single heap then best case you need 3N memory and worst case you have a free block of memory of size N-1, the string of size N-1, free block of size N-1, string of size N, free block of size N-1. So overall 3N - 5N memory.

But the libc probably has an optimized malloc using different memory pools for different allocations sizes (8, 16, 32, 64, ... bytes). Then the blocks allocated for smaller strings will never be reused for larger strings and you end up with 2 blocks of size 8, 16, 32, 64, ... each. Or 2N log_2 N of unusable memory. Although at larger size (multiple of page size) malloc will mmap and munmap blocks needed for the string and show 0 overhead. But for smallish N you easily end up with >20N memory usage.

For the `l += c` and `reverse` case the same problem exists, but you have far fewer allocations as the string grows in larger steps. For the simple malloc you still need maybe 3-4N memory and for the optimized malloc you probably end up with only N log_2 N memory usage (assuming the string doubles in size). Or 10N where the first method had 20N.

In conclusion: Both methods can run with about the same memory but the inability or inefficiency of reusing freed memory will make a big difference on the allocated total memory. It's the overhead of the memory system that kills you, not the memory used by the strings.

If you really want to minimize memory usage then use `reserve` on the string to make it allocate the final size of the string at the start. Then add all the characters and last reverse it. Then you truly only need N memory.

Answer (score 1):

`c+l` results in a new `std::string` (temporary) object which holds the new string contents, meaning the old string's contents prefixed by `c`.

Now, where should this `std::string` object store the string data? It can't reuse the memory of `l`, since at that point we don't know yet that the string is going to be assigned to `l`. In general we might want to reuse the `l` with the old string contents.

So this temporary has to allocate memory for the whole (prefixed) string and copy the contents into it.

Of course, then we assign the temporary string to `l` and in that case (since the temporary string won't be usable anymore afterwards) `l` can just reuse the memory used by the temporary object.

The compiler might realize how these two steps will end up with only one string object in the end and might skip the extra allocation, but I think that is generally unlikely.

With `l += c;`, no extra string object is created. Instead you are directly appending to `l`. Now it could be the case that `l` doesn't have enough memory reserved to append the extra `c` into. In that case it is also likely to reallocate memory and copy the original string contents to the new larger allocation. But that would only happen for certain sizes of `l`. If you repeatedly add characters like this, then this will happen only occasionally and the strategy used by the standard library to reallocate memory will make it so that there is only a constant factor in time cost. However, you still might be getting lucky that the *maximum* memory used doesn't exceed the limit.

If reallocation is required, then the two shown code snippets should use roughly the same maximum memory (in this particular step).

Of course your second example results in a reserved string. I think you might have intended to reverse it before appending `c` as well.

You can keep using `c+l` though. You should just make sure to indicate that the contents of `l` are not required anymore after that operation (because `l` will be replaced by the result of `c+l` anyway). That is done with `std::move`:

```
// for std::move
#include<utility>

/*...*/

l = c + std::move(l);
```

That should have about the same memory usage as your second case, but shouldn't require moving all characters twice to reverse twice.

Alternatively as mentioned by @TedLyngmo in the comments, the most straight-forward way to append a character at the beginning is probably to use the `insert` member function which allows you to specify where exactly you want to add the character:

```
l.insert(l.begin(), c);
```

Neither of all of these are time efficient. If you have to repeatedly add characters at the beginning, but not at the end, then it would be better to only store the reversed version of the string and modify the rest of the algorithm to work with the reversed string. Appending to the end of a string is usually cheap, but appending to the front is always time costly.

Comment: but using std::move() will  increase the time complexity

Comment: @ShubhamThakur No, it will not affect time complexity and it should reduce the actual time required.

Answer (score 0):

`l = c + l` will allocate a new string object, and then overwrite the old one (when you assign).

`l += c` will do the extension in-place.

Let's say `l` has length `N`. `c` has length one of course.

So `c + l` has length `N + 1`. So it uses `N+1` space, plus `N` space for the original `l` we have already. So `2N+1` space total.

`l += c` just adds it in-place, so we just need `N+1` space total.

(of course, we don't know specifically how exactly these are implemented, but this should give you an idea of the memory usage.)

Comment: Note:  The `l += c` will not prepend `c` to the front of `l`.  The assignment `l = c + l` may preprend the `c` to the front of `l`.